# Get iBeacon minor/major in background

Tags: ios, bluetooth, ibeacon

Is it possible to detect the minor/major of an iBeacon, that is in background.

For example:

Device A: App is in background
Device B: App is in foreground

Device B, need to get the minor/major informations of Device A.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

**An iOS device cannot transmit at all as an iBeacon when it is in the background.**  If you try to do so with Device A, a BLE advertisement will still come out, but it will not meet the iBeacon standard.  It will therefore be impossible to read the identifiers by Device B, regardless of whether Device B is in the foreground or the background.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24165073/1461050) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

As long as Device A is broadcasting the iBeacon information, Device B should be able to "see" it.

Answer (score 0):

Ranging for proximity does not work in the background, but if you use `-startMonitoringForRegion`, you should get a `-didEnterRegion` and `-didExitRegion` delegate callback where you can detect the major/minor information about the region.